# Using IDataErrorInfo and setting Validation.HasError style

Tags: wpf, validation, idataerrorinfo

In WPF using `IDataErrorInfo` and Style I want to create form where I can provide end user three different status while validating data
To make the scenario more clear

1) I have textbox next to it I have icon which provides end user what kind of input textbox expects  - Initial status with information icon

2) As soon as user enter data it validates it and decides whether it is valid or not 
- most of the time it will show cross (X) icon saying invalid data

3) As it is validating on `UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"` it will turn cross icon to green check mark as soon as it gets validated

i.e

```
[         ] i (tooltip- Any valid user name )
[Ga       ] X (tooltip- Invalid user name. Must be 5 char long)
[Gaurav   ] * (it will show only correct icon, meaning valid value)
```

How can I achieve this using `IDataErrorInfo` and Style, I tried doing that but as soon as my form gets loaded it invalidates all the data and shows cross icon at the first time. I want to show different tooltip and different icon for three states (`Initial info`, `Invalid data`, `Valid data`)

Answer (score 1):

IDataErrorInfo does not contain any means of representing three states. It only knows "error" and "no error".

The best solution may be to circumvent the use of IDataErrorInfo via the following:

1. Create a property for each validated field that provides the three-state status for its related field.
2. Bind ContentControls in the view to these three-state properties.
3. Set a single style for all of these new ContentControls.
4. Use Triggers in the Style to assign the ContentControl.ContentTemplate property for the error state and the valid state. For the initial state, use a Setter in the Style itself to display nothing.

You may also have to create properties for each field's tooltip text as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can find a great example here [WPF Apps With The Model-View-ViewModel Design Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)